# How to get value inside ng-change?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input field:

```
 '<input check-value-type' +
            ' type-value="$$node.type_value$$" ' +
            'ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index" ' +
            'type="text" ' +
            'placeholder="Value ($$node.type_value$$)"' +
            'class="form-control" ng-change="changeArrayValue()" ' +
            'ng-model="node.value[$index]">' +
```

How to pass current value into: `ng-change="changeArrayValue()"`

I tried as: `ng-change="changeArrayValue(node.value[$index])"`

Comment: there is no need to pass any data, as `node.value` should be accesible inside controller `$scope.node.value`., angularjs 2 way binding takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from your code; you are creating Angular JS directives / html code within your js file.

This is totally wrong ! !!! and you shall not do that.
Add a proper template; than you can access to the value with ng-model

Comment: It sholud be `ng-model` with `$index`. Cause I need to get value from each inputs

Comment: I create input element dinamicly depending of type value. If it is array, I create input by count of array elements

Comment: if it is created in JS; this is wrong and not following angular JS philosophy. Expect a lot a behaviour not working normally doing it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are doing there is correct but if you have a value field in the input tag then I think you are looking for $event.target.value

Try `ng-change="changeArrayValue($event.target.value)`

Comment: It sholud be `ng-model` with `$index`. Cause I need to get value from each inputs

Comment: If you are setting the value using node.value then there is no need for sending the value. You can just send $index and it will be accessible in the controller. My answer works if you are setting the value attribute of input, which you are not.